# Web scraped data will not merge or split

Tags: r

Working on a personal challenge, learning how to scrape information from the internet. I have three different sources I am using, which are all tennis data specifically. One of the data sets will not split or merge. It seems that the cells/observations are characterized as character strings, but will not act as such when matching, splitting, merging, etc. Any tips on how to get this scraped data to split (i.e. Player > Player First Name and Player Last Name). If I am able to gain this insight, the merging should following along relatively easily.

```
elo = htmlParse("http://tennisabstract.com/reports/atp_elo_ratings.html")
class(elo)
elo.table = readHTMLTable(elo, header=T, which=5,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using which I like to directly specify the table so if the website adds a table above the one I am interested in it will not break my code.  I just went in and manually set the classes of the columns.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

elo = htmlParse("http://tennisabstract.com/reports/atp_elo_ratings.html")

elo.table = readHTMLTable(elo, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Drop out the duplicate header
Table <- elo.table$reportable[-1,]


Table %>%
  transmute(
    Rank = as.numeric(Rank)
    ,Player
    ,PlayerFirst = gsub('(.*)\\s(.*)', '\\1', Player)
    ,PlayerLast = gsub('(.*)\\s(.*)', '\\2', Player)
    ,Age = as.numeric(Age)
    ,Elo = as.numeric(Elo)
    ,PeakMatch = `Peak Match`
    ,PeakYear = as.numeric(gsub('([0-9]{,4})\\s(.*)', '\\1',PeakMatch))
    ,PeakResult = gsub('([0-9]{,4})\\s(.*)\\s([QFRS132648]{1,4})', '\\3',PeakMatch)
    ,PeakMatch = gsub('([0-9]{,4})\\s(.*)\\s([QFRS132648]{1,4})', '\\2',PeakMatch)
    ,PeakAge = as.numeric(`Peak Age`)
    ,PeakElo = as.numeric(`Peak Elo`)
  )
```

Comment: Right, but the code above also will not split or merge. If you run the code then try to split the Player column, it will not split. It is as if the cells are not editable.

`code`Table$PlayerLast <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(Table$Player), " "), "[", 2)
Table$PlayerFirst <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(Table$Player), " "), "[", 1)

Comment: I added the gsub lines to split the player names.  They say in human speak :)   the first string can be anything then there is a space and the second string can be anything.  the `\\1` and `\\2` grab the first and the second string respectively

Comment: I also added some extra regex for splitting our the peak result F, QF, R16, etc. and the year.  This data is kind of fun :)

Comment: The gsub lines did it. Thanks for that, really appreciate it. Would you recommend manually setting the classes to the columns for all scrapes?

Comment: Yes, if you like Tennis, I am incorporating a couple of scrapes together to look at the aggregate top 100 using this Elo rating, ATP rating and forward-looking next weeks ATP Ranking (tennis has a sort of whacky ranking system).

Comment: Elo is a bit of a strange one but you could always build your own method.  If you get a group of scrapers written put it up on Github so I can check them out

Comment: For sure. I am really in my preliminary stages of scraping and compiling, but it's an awesome learning experience. Hoping to get more in-depth to one day build my own Elo Rating method.